# Iterating Images in Directory By Name

Tags: python, string, loops, directory

Hopefully this'll be relatively easy to answer as I'm still new to Python.

I need to for-iterate through images of name **[x]img[y]** where x and y are identifiers that determine how the image is processed. x determines process and is valued 1 or 2 and y determines one of the values to be used in processing.

So, in pseudo-code:

```
directory = 'my/path/to/images'
for image in directory:
    if x = 1:
        do process a with y
    elif x = 2:
        do process b with y
    else: print "ERROR"
```

I'm not familiar enough yet with the code and extracting values from strings to piece together the various different examples I've seen around. I get the feeling I should be able to turn the string into an array and read the 1st and 5th values as integers, right?

Your help is very much appreciated and if you'd like to get a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish with this project I've made a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/AcrimoniousMirth/Project-Adam-3D-SCANNER-CODE).

Many thanks :)

---

**EDIT**

---

Thanks to *Ely* for getting me this far however that introduced another error. Here's the test code I'm using to open the directory, which contains files *1img2.png, 1img4.png* and *2img1.png*.

```
import os
import re
DIRECTORY = '/home/pi/Desktop/ScannerDev/TestPhotos/'


for img_filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    x, y = os.path.splitext(img_filename)[0].split('img')
    print 'Camera is ', x
    print 'Image is ', y
"""
for img_filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    a = re.search('^(.*)img(.*)\.png$', img_filename)
    if a is None:
        break
    else:
        x = a.group(1)
        y = a.group(2)
    print 'Camera is ', x
    print 'Image is ', y
"""
```

Which returns:

```
Camera is  2
Image is  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iteratorTEST.py", line 10, in <module>
    x, y = os.path.splitext(img_filename)[0].split('img')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: @usr2564301 When my problem is solved I will accept the answer that solved it. If you look closely at my edit you'll see the return code shows a ValueError. That there is the 'remaining problem' :)

Comment: @AcrimoniousMirth Does the test directory have any other kinds of files in it which are being iterated? I created my own test directory with the same image names and directory names you are using. When I copy/paste your code and run it on my laptop, it works with no errors.

Comment: No, which is the odd thing. It's completely empty but for those 3 images. If there was another type of file I'd expect that issue too. I'm going to try renaming all of the images just because that's all I can think of at the moment. **EDIT** I found the issue. Some hidden folder. I'll have to add a clause to skip if not of that type

Comment: You could also filter out things that don't meet your assumptions, such as `for img_filename in filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.png'), os.listdir(DIRECTORY)`.

Comment: @ely hahah, I actually got right onto that once I found the hidden files and put that in a separate answer to make it clear. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) for iterating over the image files in the directory:

```
for img_filename in os.listdir('my/path/to/images'):

    # in case you don't need to worry about anything but 'img'.
    x, y = img_filename.split('img')

    # in case you want to remove .png as in the comments.
    x, y = os.path.splitext(img_filename)[0].split('img')

    # do stuff here
```

If you want to enforce your assumption, say of a .png file name, when iterating the directory, you could do this:

```
raw_files = os.listdir(DIRECTORY)
for img_filename in filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.png'), raw_files):
    ...
```

or

```
for img_filename in [x for x in os.listdir(DIRECTORY) if x.endswith('.png')]:
    ...
```

or various other variations of the idea.

Note that you may also want to further post-process the result of `x` and `y` above, like converting them to `int`, or removing any file extension (if present in the file name), and there are various other helper functions in the `os` module that will help with it.

This solution makes a hard assumption that the files follow your given format exactly, and that the special string `img` only appears once in the file name, and acts as a perfect separator between the `X` portion and the `Y` portion you need. You'll have to do some additional processing if this assumption is not true.

Comment: You can also access characters in string as if it was an array by str[index] and in if condition you can compare it to string directly right? like x == '1'

Comment: Yes, you can base your logic on the string-valued result of `x` if you don't strictly need to perform integer operations on it.

Comment: @ely Thanks for the quick reply! Yes, each image will be    ximgy.png though y will go into multiple digits! The split tool is excellent, I'll give this a shot :)

Comment: @ely so is there a way to remove ".png" when reading before extracting the y value? Or another operator like split?

Comment: you will need a regular expression for that `a = re.search('^(.*)img(.*)\.png$', filename) x = a.group(1) y = a.group(2)`

Comment: @AcrimoniousMirth I would use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to remove the extension, and try very very hard to avoid using regular expressions. I added this to the answer above.

Comment: @PapeK24 thanks for that, I adapted it to my code like so:    ` for img_filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    a = re.search('^(.*)img(.*)\.png$', img_filename)
    if a is None:
  break
    else:
        x = a.group(1)
        y = a.group(2)
    print 'Camera is ', x
    print 'Image is ', y`    however it only prints the x and y of one image in the directory (which contains 3 for testing)

Comment: @ely thanks, I just tried that and got back "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: @AcrimoniousMirth That likely means you have some files for which the filename doesn't match your stated assumption of `XimgY.png`, and so when it performs the split operation, you don't get the right results. Check on the file name assumptions to try to locate the mistake you're making.

Comment: @ely I checked that, I have 3 images stored as '1img2.png`, `1img4.png` and `2img1.png` so I'm not seeing any issues. It always reads the last image first then produces that error. I'll edit the original question to show the full code and returned error.

Comment: What will happen when a folder name ends with this string? There should be a way to reliably filter on files only.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to *ely* for the help with this and to the other's who's answers helped and show alternative methods. **I am writing this as a separate answer to give the final solution we came to in its own, clear area**.

```
# To extract operators x and y from file named ximgy.png
# where y may be multiple characters long.
import os
DIRECTORY = '/home/pi/Desktop/ScannerDev/TestPhotos/'

for img_filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    # This ensure hidden files or others don't cause issues
    if img_filename.endswith(".png"):
        x, y = os.path.splitext(img_filename)[0].split('img')
        print 'Camera is ', x
        print 'Image is ', y
        # DO STUFF HERE
```